# Load image in Svelte before component mounts

Tags: image, three.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit with SvelteCubed to run Three JS within a Svelte component. For the materials I am using (rather large) textures. ThreeJS's `THREE.TextureLoader();` requires `document` to work, since it creates an image and sets `src`.

However, this means that to use it, I need to put it in `onMount()`, which seems to stop the images being cached and removes the snappiness of SvelteKit using clientside rendering, since they are loaded fresh every time, and often require a manual reload.

I am using Vite's `import image from "path"`, but this doesn't load the image into a format useable by a shader, it just gives me a path to use. Is there a non-DOM based option that I can use before mounting and SvelteKit will cache?

Comment: Use that image path in your textureloader.load() method to get a texture. You can then use that texture in your materials.

Comment: That works, but has to be done in onMount(), which means the image isn't cached